# Are TreeSet.floor() and TreeSet.ceiling() methods missing in Android?

Tags: java, android, treeset

this one is a deep mystery to me.

Take a look at this:

```
TreeSet<Long> s = new TreeSet<Long>();
s.add(Long.valueOf(1));
s.add(Long.valueOf(4));
s.add(Long.valueOf(6));
s.add(Long.valueOf(9));

Long upper = s.ceiling(Long.valueOf(5));
Long lower = s.floor(Long.valueOf(5));
```

In a normal Java VM, this compiles and runs beautifully.

If I take a look at Android's API doc, and even according to:
http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/android-core/platform-libcore/java/util/TreeSet.java.htm

the methods ceiling and floor should be there.

But if I try to use them in Eclipse + Android SDK (Build Target is "8"), Eclipse is telling me that floor(Long) and ceiling(Long) are not defined for class TreeSet

Any idea?

Thanks,
Karlheinz

Comment: I don't know, but to me it looks like you have to specify a Comparator

Comment: @Bart: Consider a `TreeSet<MyCustomObject>`. How would it compare them?

Comment: @Martijn, sure, with a custom object that is not `Comparable`, you'd need to pass add a `Comparator` to the c-tor. But in the example of Karlheinz, a `Long` is used, which _is_ already `Comparable` so there's no need for a `Comparator`.

Comment: @Bart: Where should we tell it which Comparator to use? I can't find any method...

Comment: @Martijn, these comment boxes are not suited for question and answers. If you don't understand why there is no need for a `Comparator` in this case, I recommend looking into it yourself first, do a tutorial on sorting with Java, or create a question of your own here on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

floor is API level 9, same goes for ceiling.

[Android javadoc for TreeSet](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TreeSet.html#floor%28E%29)

Comment: Well, that was easy. I didn't expect java.util classes to change that way in a fairly late Android release. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> In a normal Java VM, this compiles and runs beautifully.

Not in my JVM (which is 1.5.0_22). There I have `headSet(...)` and `tailSet(...)`.

Comment: Yes, Javadoc says that actually ceiling was new with Java 1.6 as well.